# Using variables in nitroscript view, NitroSell system

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm working on a 'view' used on a NitroSell based e-commerce store. It seems to be a proprietary system, a PHP framework, and support is minimal.

I'm trying to find a way to use my own PHP script in the view (in the same way that one can in Laravel or CodeIgniter), to do some calculations based on custom cart item atributes.

Here's part of a basket view, and in the middle is pseudo-code for doing some calcs with vars pulled from the system.

```
{ifThereAre basketitems}
  {foreach basketitem}
    {if (basketitem['product_weblinxcustomtext1'] eq 'All')}
      // [start pseudo-code]
        $myvar = basketitem['product_weblinxcustomnumber1'];
        $mynewvar = $myvar*10;
        echo $mynewvar;
      // [end pseudo-code]
    {endIf}
  {endforeach} 
{endIfThereAre}
```

The problem is that I can't find a way to get that pseudo-code to run. I've tried:

```
<?php $mynewvar = $myvar*10;?>
<?$mynewvar = $myvar*10;?>
{$mynewvar = $myvar*10;}
{{$mynewvar = $myvar*10;}}
{mynewvar = myvar*10;}
{{mynewvar = myvar*10;}}
```

...and none of them work, most of them appear as HTML in the rendered view. It might be that ALL php views is stripped, but I'd like to hear any more ideas you might have. We have no access to the Controllers/Models, as it's managed 'online' and only the templates are made available for editing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, all PHP is stripped from your code.

NitroSell works the same way as other eCommerce platforms exposing templates that you can modify to suit your needs. It is a proprietary system similar to Smarty that people might be more familiar with.

The tags marked with {} are replaced with developer defined PHP on the server side.

There is nothing stopping you using js. In your case

```
<script language="javascript">
 myNewVar = myvar*10;
</script>
```

Hope that helps
James

Comment: Thanks for the response. In this case, we need to be able to do these calculations in an email template, so javascript isn't viable (it gets ignored/stripped/blocked by email clients). If you have any other ideas please let me know, but if not, you've at least confirmed that what were trying to do is not possible.